# How to perform the CRUD operations on the datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable, crud

I have a grid view , i want its data source to be an `(offline) DataTable` to make the CRUD operations [offline] then after the confirm i will store the confirmed version in my database.

---

- How to make the CRUD operations(insert,update,delete) with the
  `DataTable` through `LINQ` if possible?Example
- What's the best way to keep the last version among the post backs of
  the page?

Comment: Linq is used for Queries, not for updates.

Comment: Then could u recommend a way to do the crud operations on the `datatable`?

Comment: I can only recommend doing it w/o a DataTable.

Comment: Why do you want to store data offline? please explain the senario

Comment: DataSets aren't really bad, just outdated. If you're starting something new, look around a little first.

Comment: The Insert/update/Delete operation are specifically in a single page?

Answer (score 2):

1. I suggest you google about using `DataTable` and `DataSet`s with `DataAdapter`s; ([here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3805/Inserting-relational-data-using-DataSet-and-DataAd)'s a start) if you're only using it in a simple scenario, it's quite straightforward.
2. You can store data in the user's `Session` object. (See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx))

Comment: Storing Tables in the Session really hurts your scalability. Better think that through first.